# Hide Media Controls on Lockscreen at Android 11

Tags: android, mediasession

I use a custom MediaPlay-Service to play my files on Dropbox with a custom widget for all necessary controls. Since Android Studio 11 my custom widget isn't showing on Lockscreen.